# Xcode iPhone 4/5 Screen Size Both

Tags: iphone, xcode, screen-size

I am making an application in Xcode, and I need to make it for both iPhone 4 and 5. But since the iPhone 5 has a bigger screen, it messes my application up.

Once I place the labels for the size of iPhone 4 and then test it on the iPhone 5 the labels are all misplaced. Is there a way to make them stay?

Comment: You should check autoresizing masks too, which are backward compatible, unlike autolayout which is an iOS6 feature.

Comment: New on this so. Don't know how to accept the answer?

Comment: @user1702518 you can click the checkmark next to it - it will turn green.

Comment: Weird did not se it before, but it says i can accept it in 4 mins :)

Comment: Is autolayout the only acceptable way of doing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use iOS 6's new [autolayout](http://www.raywenderlich.com/20881/beginning-auto-layout-part-1-of-2) feature (if you want to be iOS5-compatible, you can still have autoresizing masks).

Answer (score 0):

You need to position your labels based on the View Height of the device(don't have to worry about width, since iPhone 4 and 5 both have the same width. But this would apply for a universal app targeting iPad and iPhone).

For instance, if yours is a View Based Application, find the view height of the superview using `self.view.frame.size.height`, and determine all label/view placements based on this property.

And test for both screen sizes on the iOS Simulator.